# How to generate a certificate with fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler gaves me a message box with the following message:

```
The server [<LINK>] Requests a client certificate. 
Please save a client certificate using the filename:

C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Fiddler2\ClientCertificate.cer
```

i have already tried using this FiddlerScript (that i found on internet)

```
static function  OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    oSession["https-Client-Certificate"]= "C:\\Yourcerfilelocation.cer"; 

}
```

But i get the following message error:

```
Compiler error on line: 1

Valid only in a class definition
```

i want to know how can i save the certificate as this .cer file for Fiddler to use it, without getting errors

Comment: This is a syntax error. Look up tutorials for JScript.NET.

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerScript handlers definitions should be put in a class - this is how extensibility point is designed.

For example, the default FiddlerScript definition (the one installed with Fiddler and visible in the FiddlerScript tab) has the following structure:

```cs
import System;
import System.Windows.Forms;
import Fiddler;

// ...

class Handlers
{
   // ...
   static function OnPeekAtResponseHeaders(oSession: Session) {
   // ...
   }
}

// ...
```

If you put the `OnBeforeRequest` handler in the `Handlers` class, e.g. next to the `OnPeekAtResponseHeaders`, this should clear the syntax error, and the handler will be executed.